# PHP get random line from CSV without loop

Tags: php, csv, random

I have multiple big CSV files with more than 1 million lines. I can't change that.

I need in a loop, get a random line of a random CSV file and output this line.

For now I have :

```
        for ($i=0; $i < 50; $i++) {
            $randomFile = $files[array_rand($files)];

            if (($handle = fopen($randomFile, "r")) !== FALSE) {
                //HERE I NEED TO GET A RANDOM LINE OF $handle FILE
            }
        }
```

How can I get a random line of my CSV `$handle`, without loop like all solution I see everywhere ?

I already tried loop solution but my CSv files are too big and my script freeze each time.

Thanks !

Comment: You can't, the ___only___ way to do this is to loop; you can't even count the lines without a loop.... and with big files this will take time..... but why are you doing this with a csv files anyway? Why not use a database?

Comment: I totally agree with @MarkBaker above ^^^, It's going to be a costly exercise reading a file that size. Even if you use `file_get_contents()`/`explode()`/`count()`/`rand()` to fetch a random element/line.

Comment: @MarkBaker what about `array_rand(file($randomFile))`? There may be a loop in the PHP methods themselves, but not explicitly... *Edit:* of course I know that this will load the whole file into memory, but that's not what the question is about :)

Comment: @Robbie - you try loading a file with a million records into a PHP array.... even if you set unlimited memory, you're going to hit memory limits and still take forever

Comment: @MarkBaker if there's a specific requirement for it, server specs can be adjusted to suit. All purely theoretical of course, because it's more likely that the task requirements need to be looked at!

Comment: 32-bit PHP 5.x, memory requirement for an array with 1 million records of 1byte strings is about 76,000,000 bytes (76MB)

Comment: @MarkBaker I've got a server which allows 2gb per process - anything's possible ;)

Comment: Then you need to factor in the real size of the data..... and allow for the execution time for PHP to allocate and subsequently de-allocate that memory

Comment: Then he may use fread with an array which implements ArrayIterator.

Answer (score 0):

Is that solve the problem ?

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i < 50; $i++) {
    $randomFile = $files[array_rand($files)];

    if (($handle = fopen($randomFile, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $randomLineIndex = array_rand($data = fgetcsv($handle, filesize($randomFile), ","));
        print_r($data[$randomLineIndex]);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Updated Answer :

According To @Robbie's answer below in the comment section would be with better performance.

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i < 50; $i++) {
    $randomFile = $files[array_rand($files)];
    $randomLineIndex = array_rand(file($randomFile));    
    print_r($data[$randomLineIndex]);
}
```

Comment: `array_rand(file($randomFile))` would probably be the easiest

Comment: Yes Robbie it is oneliner and probably better performance no need to parse by ','.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible. You can read file to array and get a random cell from array (it requires more computer resources, not good for big file) or you can generate random number and go to this line using loop and break after reading needed line.